Why React Hooks must be used inside function components?
I'm studing React and got a question about 'Why React Hooks must be used inside function components'
I wrote useContext outside of the function components by mistake, and got a error message.
React Hook "useContext" cannot be called at the top level. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function.

I thought maybe it is to manage sequence for calling hooks, and I read React docs to find out exact reason.
But only I can find was 'call them at the top level in the body of a function component' line.
I know it's very silly question to ask but I can't find nice reason to make me understand.
I'd really appreciate your help.

Because it breaks the rules of hooks. From the docs "By following this rule, you ensure that all stateful logic in a component is clearly visible from its source code."

They need to be used inside components because they are directly tied to an instance of a component.
For example, useState creates a state of that component instance. Calling use state outside a component wouldn't have any effect, because there is no component instance for the state to be associated with.
useContext tells react to search upward in the component tree for a context provider of the correct type, and give you its value. This is relative to the current component's spot in the component tree. If you called it outside a component, there is no component instance from which to start the search.

Hooks are made to function with the lifecycle of a React component. React can track the state and lifecycle of a function component when a Hook is called inside of it. This tracking mechanism would not function if Hooks were called outside of this context.
